# Wordpress stuck on loading gears after migration to DigitalOcean - Can't access WP-ADMIN

Tags: mysql, wordpress, migration, loading, digital-ocean

I set up my wordpress site locally, then tried moving it to Digital Ocean today.
I made a zip of the HTML folder
Created a MYSQL database backup
Created a database with same name, user,pw on digital ocean and imported the backup
uploaded the html to /var/www/html (after setting up apache2 and phpmyadmin)

but my website is stuck at the loading gears
and I can't access wp-admin. it says:
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

I tried checking and chaning the wp_option values. set them to my new url.
I also tried adding :
`// Site URLS (override DB settings) define('WP_HOME','http://www.royaltytowing.com.au');     //<-- NO TRAILING / define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.royaltytowing.com.au');  //<-- NO TRAILING /`

still no luck

Comment: Use a migration plugin for this; there are many things to fix up in your database and files when you move a site from one place (localhost) to another (some public URL). I like Duplicator but there are several others.

Comment: Thanks. I somehow managed to enter WP admin by disabling all plugins. But now when I try to install any plugin from the market it says "Error: Could not connect to the server. Please verify the settings are correct."  I am using the correct FTP credentials, I have chown -R /var/www in my file system. what am I doing wrong?